# How to not expose a function in rpc and access the function through tight coupling?

Tags: substrate, polkadot

I have a function in say schelling_game pallet:

```
pub fn create_tree(key: SumTreeName, k: u64) -> DispatchResult {}
```

Now I am accessing the function in template pallet using tight coupling:

```
schelling_game::Pallet::<T>::create_tree(key, 2);
```

But the problem is create_tree is exposed in rpc, anyone can call create_tree as it is public. I want only to call it under template pallet or some other pallet without exposing it to rpc. Making it private doesn't work as I can't access it in template pallet.

Comment: I think there's a way to enlist the allowed origin that can pass the Rpc though rpc proxy. In case of http rpc, this might be of a help: https://paritytech.github.io/jsonrpc/jsonrpc_http_server/enum.AccessControlAllowOrigin.html